# How to simplify $\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{6}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently stuck on this question and would really appreciate any hint at all.
We have been told to use the fact that:${n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-2 \choose k-1}+...+{k-1 \choose k-1}$

So far I have done the following:
$$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{6} = \sum_{r=3}^n {r \choose 3}$$ $$=\sum_{r=3}^n {r-1 \choose 2}+{r-2 \choose 2}+...+{2 \choose 2}$$
$$=[{2 \choose 2}]+[{2 \choose 2}+{3 \choose 2}]+[{2 \choose 2}+{3 \choose 2}+{4 \choose 2}]+...+[{2 \choose 2}+...+{n-1 \choose 2}]$$
$$=(n-2){2 \choose 2}+(n-3){3 \choose 2}+...+(n-(n-1)){n-1 \choose 2}$$

I am not sure where to go from there, but I know that we are meant to get the answer ${n+1 \choose 4}$. Thank you very much!

Comment: prove by induction that $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{6}=\frac{1}{4} (n-2) (n-1) n (n+1)$$

Comment: Backwards, our sum is the one in the quoted formula, with $k-1=3$ and $n-1$ replaced by $n$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to fill the gap in my reasoning by tracking back from the answer, using your hint!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the denominator in the right hand side should be 24.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$
\binom{r}{3}=\binom{r+1}{4}-\binom{r}{4}
$$
The the series becomes telescopic.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Notice, $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{6}$$$$=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{r=0}^{n}(r^3-3r^2+2r)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^3-3\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^2+2\sum_{r=0}^{n}r\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\left(\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-3\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: this does not use the hint given to OP :-)

Comment: Can't the above expression be simplified ?

Answer (score 0):

The hint (or fact) given that you are supposed to use is the same as 
$$\sum_{r=k-1}^{N-1} \binom r{k-1}=\binom Nk$$

Putting $k=3$ and $N=n+1$gives
$$\sum_{r=3}^n\binom r3=\binom {n+1}4$$